# Create folder from server to client in intranet using php

Tags: php

I have a server and i need to create a folder in the clients side and store a file for security purpose 
Is it possible please let me know.
 Thank you

Comment: are u asking about socket connection??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server cannot have this level of interaction with the client. So it's not possible from PHP for sure.

It **might** be possible with JavaScript, and I'm not even sure there's a reliable way to do it there, because browsers are normally not allowed to touch the file systems.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP its not possible. PHP run on the server. For this you need a programm that has enough rights on your system and it must run on the client side a **JAVA Applett** or **Flash** with enough system rights.

But i think its not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

For "**security purpose**", PHP does not and will never allow this sort of interaction with a computer. You can download files and then the person can put it in the folder, that way the user has knowledge they even have the file on their computer, otherwise there is no way unless using Java (with the correct rights of course)