# Can I create a directory in client PC?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I have multiple questions

1. Can we create a directory in client machine ?
2. Can we check the running browser's default download path?

My requirement is that the user will download a BLOB data from my DB that time I want to create a folder in client machine and use that folder to save the blob data.

Can this be done using **javascript,jquery,ajax,php,angularjs ?**

Comment: This is not possible without a browser extension. There are good reasons for that: primary that would mean a huge privacy breach. You simply cannot access the client machine from outside. You always need the explicit interaction of the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create folder from server to client in intranet using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969572/create-folder-from-server-to-client-in-intranet-using-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't create a folder in client PC using JS.**(don't even bother looking with HTML and CSS)

The best way you could accomplish something as you describe is to give a .zip to your client, so while extracting it, it creates his own container (the folder). But you must be sure that the people who intend using your web application knows how a .zip works.

Comment: It is not a solution. Because different OS has different file structure. So, it is not possible PHP to access the folder, because the directory path will different.

Comment: Zip file works in pretty much all OS. And it will uncompress to fit the right structure to fit the OS.

Comment: I am not talking about zip file. I try to mean the folder structure of every OS. Like say, the if I create a folder in desktop, then the path in windows, Linux and MAC will be different.

Comment: Why is the path on user computer important. If you want them to download a folder full of files, they should be able to put them where they want.

Comment: @Louis The same client machine maybe used by multiple user so I need a common place to save this blob file ...  Is **flash** or **actionscript** is capable of doing this ?

Comment: @MikePappa No web language should be able to have access to any folder in any computer. That would be a huge flaw in security to allow it.

Comment: @Louis Then how a hacker can do it? If it possible by hacking I am ready to do that

Comment: @MikePapa They're pushing a program that people often install by mistake. (Spamming the Next button) then, it gains access to computer. Please, if it is not in a controlled environement like a company, dont do that. Its illegal if the user doesn't consent.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP you can't do anything in the client PC. PHP is a server side programming language. So, it is running only in the server. When you make any request to the server then only PHP performs. In the browser end or client side only HTML, CSS and JS works.

Comment: What u mean to say, is it possible using **HTML, CSS and JS works** ?  if then how?

Comment: No. It is also not possible using HTML, CSS and JS. In the term 'works' I try to mean that the browser can identify only HTML, CSS and JS. That's why if you go to the source code of any webpage you will have only HTML,CSS and JS. There is no PHP code.

Comment: Is it possible using **flash or actionscript **?

Comment: No. You need to create an OS based application or browser add on.